# Static Ip on Device or via Router

Tags: pi-3, networking

I have a Pi3B with multiple Oses on it that use wired( kodi, ubuntu) and wireless connections( Iot). I want to assign a static IP but not sure how to go about this.

I can assign it using the router and mac address or I can put it on the device itself

Does putting it on the device apply it to all Oses installed?
Can I install it on both?
Can I reserve more than one IP for the same MAC?

Comment: **WHY??** Unless you are running a standalone network or Access Point there is no need. You cannot setup a "static IP" address on your router, although you can get most to assign the same IP address to a `MAC`, how to do this depends on the router, and is not a Pi question. The procedure for assigning a static IP address varies between OS. If you search this site you will find literally hundreds of posts.

Comment: Apparently similar question has already been asked. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address

Answer (score 1):

It will make more sense to setup "IP and Mac binding" on your router in your case for whatever reason you'd want to run multiple OS. The procedure varies from router to router, but all you need is the MAC address of RPi eth0 or RPi wlan0 MAC address. run `ifconfig` to find out the MAC address, for RPi built-in `eth0` and `wlan0` when your RPi is connect to the network, the mac address has a prefix of `b8:27:eb:??.??.??`.

No, you can't map more than 1 IP for the same MAC.