# Assign Static IP via berry boot commands

Tags: pi-3, static-ip, berryboot

I have a raspberry pi 3 with 4 OSs using BerryBoot. Is there a way to programmatically assign static ip via command text or configuration file using berry boot for each os on startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static Ip on Device or via Router](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/77871/static-ip-on-device-or-via-router)

Comment: @Milliways this is not a duplicate question I'm trying to add the ip dynamically using a config file rather than via the different OSes